# SQL Server 2014: SELECT only those rows that match all rows in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner in SQL Server. I am trying to solve this problem:

Select all (distinct) "item_id" from "ItemTag" table whose corresponding "tag_id" values match at least "all" values in the "UserTagList" table.

I tried a join below but instead of the result I got the query should return the item_id 5 since it has both tag_id's 3 & 4.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Below is the SQL schema

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a8a0/1)

SQL Server 2014 schema setup:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTagList (id INT);

INSERT INTO UserTagList (id) 
VALUES (3), (4);

CREATE TABLE ItemTag (id INT, item_id INT, tag_id INT);

INSERT INTO ItemTag (id, item_id, tag_id)
VALUES (1, 5, 3), (2, 5, 4), (3, 5, 6), (4, 6, 3), (5, 7, 4);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.tag_id 
FROM ItemTag AS i 
JOIN UserTagList AS u ON i.tag_id = u.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a8a0/1/0)**:

```
| item_id | tag_id |
|---------|--------|
|       5 |      3 |
|       5 |      4 |
|       6 |      3 |
|       7 |      4 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a query where `group by` and `having` are useful:

```
select i.item_id
from ItemTag i join
     UserTagList u 
     on i.tag_id = u.id
group by i.item_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from UserTagList);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my problem. Returns 0 results if there are "no" or "some" tag_id's matching in the UserTagList table and returns only those items which have all tags in the  UserTagList  table. Thanks @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

I would use a left join here with aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.item_id
FROM ItemTag t1
LEFT JOIN UserTagList t2
    ON t1.tag_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.item_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

The logic here is that if, for a given `item_id` group, one or more of its tags did not match to anything in the `UserTagList` table, then the sum in the `HAVING` clause would detect and count a null and non-matching record.